# How do I get the data(messags) coming in the last 'n' mins on the consumer side for Kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a producer that sends messages in the form of a list of dictionaries. The consumer reads messages but I am not able to fetch the messages that arrive in the last 'n' minutes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may probably add a publishedTime to the list of dictionary. Then, when you consumer fetch data, it can fetch until the published Time is too far from now

Comment: I have to do this using the processing time for each message.

Answer (score 0):

There is provision to rewind particular timestamp. In order to do that you need to manually assign partitions for topic in the consumer and then use `seek` method.